# Degree of all extensions $\mathbb Q(\alpha)/\mathbb Q$ with $\alpha$ root of $T^5-T^4+3T^3+3T^2-9T+3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

I need to find the degree of all extensions $\mathbb Q(\alpha)/\mathbb Q$ with $\alpha$ root of $T^5-T^4+3T^3+3T^2-9T+3$.

This polynomial has only one rational solution ($\alpha=1$) and the others are not easy to find.

Even if the 5 roots were easy to get, is there a way of finding those degrees without calculating them all?

I think I have a brief idea of the answer, because this poly is reducible into two factors (degree 1 and 4). Both are monic and irreducible, so the two extensions should be 1 and 4. Am I right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The degree of an extension $L/K$ with $L$ generated by a single element $\alpha$ is the degree of the *minimal polynomial* of $\alpha$. The minimal polynomial must divide $T^5-T^4+3T^3+3T^2-9T+3$ and be irreducible. So, yes, you're correct! As the irreducible factors have degree $1$ and $4$, these are the two possibilities.

Comment: Thanks, Joshua. And what about those extensions, are Galois? How could we know say without explicitly calculating the roots?

Comment: @electr0n: Checking if the extension is Galois (equivalent to normal here) requires a bit more effort. You need to ensure that all roots are rational functions of a single root $\alpha$.

Comment: That's what I meant; the other roots are too complicated to find. So...?

Comment: Why don't you ask this as a separate question: i.e. choose one of your extensions, the degree 1 or degree 4, and ask if it is Galois in another post? @ParamanandSingh has explained roughly how to check this, but you may need a little bit more help unpacking 'normal' vs 'galois'.

Comment: I will do. Thanks.